# SQL - loop query when WHERE condition comes from list

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, mariadb, heidisql

I have a mysql db table which contains a number of bibliographic records. It's formatted a little like this:

```
field content |field title |barcode
Black Beauty  |Title       |9781235842
James Joyce   |Author      |9781452585
```

There are a few dozen possible field titles.

Each record is effectively spread over a number of rows, the record is the combined rows which share the barcode.

I want to see what items have short records.

I have a working query for a specific barcode:

`select barcode, sum(length(field_content)) 
from central
where barcode = 420908032337
;`

And I have a list of 1.3k suspect barcodes. Is there a way to run the SQL query by looping through this list?

I am on a work machine and have access to HeidiSQL, git bash [including grep etc] but won't be able to install php, ruby etc for scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select barcode,
       sum(length(field_content)) AS rec_len
    from central
    GROUP BY barcode
    ORDER BY rec_len  -- display the shortest first
    LIMIT 50;   -- if you want to see just 50
```

Comment: That's fantastic. Thanks. It does create a weird first row which seems to concatenate all the barcodes in one cell but ignoring that it works perfectly.
Thanks again.        For anyone consulting this in the future - this solution tells me what the shortest records are. It doesn't do so by consulting the suspect list but it is really speedy and removes the need to consult that list.

Comment: Check `central` to see if the 'concatenate' is in it.

Answer (score 2):

No need of looping through just use a `IN` operator and supply all your barcodes values there like

```
where barcode in (1.3K list of barcodes)
```

There are many ways you can form that inlist .. using a scripting language or any. Else, create a `temporary` table. Fill it with those list of barcodes and select from that temporary table

```
where barcode in (select distinct barcodes from my_temp_table)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I gave that a go as described and while it gives me a total character count for all rows it doesn't produce the line by line result I was looking for.
I tried:
```
    select barcode, sum(length(field_content)) 
    from central
    where barcode in (select barcode from shortlist)
    ;
```
and the result was 
```
barcode[1]  604724
````

Comment: @Jack, what's that `shortlist`? and how have you pull those values in there?

Comment: Shortlist is another table containing the 1.3k values. I added them to the table with ```LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'H:\\shortlist.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE `sierra_import`.`shortlist` FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\n' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`barcode`);````